# Error trying to get disak space usage from discovered VMS using Zabbix

Tags: vmware-esxi, monitoring, vmware-vcenter, zabbix

I am trying to create a trigger on a template called Template Virt VMware Guest in order to extract the % of free space of the VMWARE VM that has the template inherited.

What I did was:

Going to the template and create the following item: And the I created a trigger for trigger it once the% of free space on each of the disks is less than 10x.

[image]

Here you have the way I configured it: But when I link it the template to some host I get the following error: What might be the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]